# Proving that $x(x^2-1)(x^2-10)=c$ cannot have five integer solutions for any real $c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, proof-writing, solution-verification

I found this question that caught my attention at MSE and  I did a solution, but I suspect something is wrong with the solution.

---

Original problem says:

> Prove that for any real values of $c$, the equation $x(x^2-1)(x^2-10)=c$ can't have $5$ integer solutions.

---

**The things I have done:**

I find stronger (?) results in this answer:

- If $c=0$, then we have $3$ integer solutions.
- If $c>0$ or $c<0$, then we have only $1$ integer solution.

This means,

- The number of integer solutions is always less than $4$.

---

Let,

$$f(x)=x(x^2-1)(x^2-10)$$

and

$$x(x^2-1)(x^2-10)=c$$

where $c\in\mathbb R, x\in\mathbb Z$.

In fact we need only $c\in\mathbb Z$. Because, if $x\in\mathbb Z$ then $c\in\mathbb Z$.

We see that $c=0$ is trivial.

$\underline{\text{Case}-1:~c>0}$

$$\begin{align}&x(x^2-1)(x^2-10)>0 ,x\in\mathbb Z \\ &\iff x\in \left\{-3, -2\right\}∪[4,+\infty)\end{align}$$

Then suppose that, $x_1≥4, x_1\in\mathbb Z $ is a solution.

If $x_2>x_1≥4$ then $f(x)$ is strictly increasing and if $4≤x_2<x_1$, then $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing. This means, if $x_1≥4$, then we have one positive integer solution.

Then, we see that $f(-3)<f(-2)<f(4)$ and $f(x)$ is strictly increasing for $x≥4$.

This implies, if $c>0$, then we have only one integer solution.

---

$\underline{\text{Case}-2:~c<0}$

Let's multiply both sides of the equation by $(-1).$

$$-x(x^2-1)(x^2-10)=-c, c<0$$

Let, $-x=t$ then

$$t(t^2-1)(t^2-10)=-c,-c>0$$

This means, for $c<0$ we have also one integer solution.

Thus, we conclude the number of integer solutions is always less than $4$.

---

Does my solution contain any errors?

Please, don't post the correct solution.

Thank you for reviewing.

Comment: it cannot have five real roots unless $c$ is between -3.724 and 3.724

Comment: @Will Hi, Will! In fact the question is about _integer_ solutions.

Comment: @JeanMarie Hi. I posted a grph as an answer. Unless $c$ is between tight bounds there are just three real solutions. If $|c| < 3.7236$ there are five real solutions, but these cannot all be integers as the largest real root is strictly between 3 and 4. That's all I had in mind.

Comment: why did you write "Please, do not post the correct solution."?
Is it mistake in writing?

Comment: @Will Jagy I see. Indeed, graphical representations are under-used... not only to help building a conjecture or verifying a result but also as real proofs when there is no interest to detail evident truths.

Comment: @JeanMarie yeah; I wish the students would get accustomed to graphing functions themselves, by hand. Most of them just refuse when I suggest it.

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you very much.! I appreciate your answer. But you might think I tend to get more specific answers about my results...

Comment: @Mahmoudalbahar  No, it is OK. But, if my solution is wrong, I can try again and find the right solution myself.  I never like ready-made solutions..$\ddot\smile$

Comment: Then in my opinion, your mathematical personality (your way of studying mathematics and dealing with its problems)  is very great.

Comment: The analysis looks reasonable. I would consider looking at $f(x)-f(k)$ for $k\in\{-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3\}$ as well, because $c=f(k)$ is where each particular $k$ is a root.

Answer (score 4):

If $c$ is bigger than the local maximum, $y$ value about
$3.723601932658154682760729230  ,$  then there are, at most, three real solutions to $x(x^2-1)(x^2-10) = c.$
Just draw a horizontal line at $y=c$ for some $c$ value of interest. Then, when $|c| \leq 3.723601932658154682760729230,$  we do get five real roots, but these are not all integers as the largest is strictly between 3 and 4.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For your answer my opinion is : your solution is correct because you analyze the problem

in good way.

for the case of $c=0$ it is trivial as you said .

for the cases  $c>0 $ and $c<0$ they are similar so I will discuss with you the case of

$c>0$ , you wrote the intervals of the integer $x$  that satisfy the case  then for

$[4,+\infty)$  you proved that there is only one solution (but the part of your

answer that $f(x)$  is strictly decreasing it is not true and you don't need it because

$f(x)$ is increasing  on $[4,+\infty)$ and this  is enough to prove that we don't have

another roots in this interval ),

and for $x\in \left\{-3, -2\right\}$ ,now if we substitute $x=-3$ in $x(x^2-1)(x^2-10)=c$

we have $c=24$  and for $x=-2$ we have $c=36$ so we can't have $x=-2$ and $x=-3$ as

solution for the same $c>0$ so as you mentioned  there are at most two solutions.

also we can say that we have only one solution for the case $c>0$ because when $c=24$ then

$x=-3$ but we don't have solutions in interval $[4,+\infty)$ because $f(4)=360$ and the

function is increasing on this interval, the same thing for $c=36$

I hope this discussion is helpful for you.